# Extjs comb wont get initial value, only display

Tags: extjs, combobox

I have a form with combo (hiddenName como).
The form loads its data from the server and sets the "selectedValue" automatically.
The combo loads its value from the server **before** the form loads its data.
If I click on submit, the displayValue will be sent to the server instead of the value even though I set the hiddenName.
**But** if I change the combo value, from then on it will submit the value and not the displayValue, as expected.
Why does the initial value that was set by the form prevent the combo from submitting its value?

This is the combo and the store:

```
var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        url: config.url,
        root: 'data',
        methos:'POST',
        fields:[{name:'userManager_employeeId'},{name:'userManager_userName'}] });

    var combo  = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        hiddenName:'userManager',
        valueField: 'userManager_employeeId',
        displayField: 'userManager_userName',
        forceSelection: true,
        mode: 'remote',    
        typeAhead: true,
        lazyInit :false,
        lazyRender:false,
        fieldLabel:     config.title,
        emptyText:'Select a value',
        roles:config.roles,
```

**EDIT**

This is the form data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "employee_employeeId": 3,
            "Affiliate_affiliateId": 8,
            "parent_affiliateId": 8,
            "userManager_employeeId": 1,
            "Affiliate_email": "avi@finexo.co.il",
            "parent_name": "First Affiliate",
            "userManager": "admin",
            "Affiliate_name": "First Affiliate",
            "user_userName": "admin",
            "user_userId": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the combo data:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "userManager_userName": "admin",
            "userManager_employeeId": 1
        },
        {
            "userManager_userName": "admin2",
            "userManager_employeeId": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the form reader:

```
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
            root: 'data',
            fields: [{
                name: 'userManager'
            }]
        })
```

This is the form data:

```
{"data":[{"userManager":"admin"}]}
```

I also tried:

```
{"data":[{"userManager":"1"}]}
```

If the form data is "admin", I see in the display 'admin' but the submitted value is also 'admin'.
If the form data is "1", I see in the display "1" and in the submit value "1".
How can i see in the display 'admin' and submit the value ("1")? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post code for how your form is loading data?

Comment: Add code where you assign value to combo

Comment: It is chosen automatically, the data is coming from the server, I think the reader does that, BTW, text fields working fine and their text are set fine as well.

Comment: I never face with such problem before but i think that if you select value in code - everything be all right.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue enough that I've got a plugin that I include on forms with combos.  In your case you need to turn off `autoload` on your combo's store.  Populate your form with the combo's valueField, like the second example you've provided.  Then modify your server side code to search for valueFields *or* displayFields, instead of just displayFields. Then you can do this once your form's loaded:

```
combo.getStore().load({
   params: { query: combo.getValue()},
   callback: function () { combo.setValue(combo.getValue()) }
});
```

This will send a request to the server just for id 1, and the server will reply with the data for the combo to fix its displayField.  `setValue` then sets the displayField and valueField. It's a workaround, but it works.